# How can I get events from a transaction receipt using Wagmi?

Tags: reactjs, wagmi

Ethers.js has `ContractReceipt` which extends `TransactionReceipt` that includes an array of events from the transaction:  https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/contracts/src.ts/index.ts#L99

Is it possible to get this array using Wagmi?  The docs say that wagmi now returns the Viem `TransactionReceipt` instead of Ethers, and it doesn't look like it has `ContractReceipt`:  https://github.com/wagmi-dev/viem/blob/136c4022c3ab4020f37333876bed788a111bff47/src/types/transaction.ts#L12

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

You need to parse the logs yourself from the Wagmi/Viem transaction receipt.  I modified the answer in this post:  https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/487

```
const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(deployment.abi);
const parsed = iface.parseLog(testReceiptData.logs[0]);
console.log('parsed', parsed);
```

The events will be present in `logged` under `args`.